# Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2) \not\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1) \not\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have proved that  $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1) \simeq \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$. This fact is a corollary of the generalized C.R.T.

I have proved also that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \simeq \mathbb{C}$. The isomorphism is given by a map $ax+b \mapsto b + ia$.

I can see why $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \not\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$. This is because a homomorphism always maps $0$ to $0$, and $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ but $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

For the same reason $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2) \not\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$. But I still need to prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2) \not\simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: There is a nilpotent element in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$, not in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-1)$. Do you see it ?

Comment: @Lierre that is $x$. I think I got it. $\mathbb{R}/(x^2)$ has nilpotent, but $\mathbb{R}/(x^2-1)$ has no, thus there is no map with zero kernel between them. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are !
More generally, isomorphic rings share all property expressible with the ring operations. And the property $$\exists x : x^2 = 0$$ is such a property.
And by the way, you should right $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ instead of $\mathbb R/(x^2)$, which, as is, is meaning less.

Comment: Also: the "maps $0$ to $0$" argument seems like it could use some filling out. Another way to talk about the difference between these two rings is to note that $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 - 1)$ has non-zero zerodivisors, which is obvious from your use of the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @DylanMoreland thank you for your comments and for your edits to my post. I had $\mathbb{R}[x]$ in mind of course.

Comment: @DylanMoreland now I see that the map $ax+b \mapsto -a+ib$ is not suitable. The right map is $ax+b \mapsto b+ia$. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\ $ if $\,{\rm char}(F) \ne 2\ $ then [by CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48426/242) $\,F[x]/(x^2-1)\, \cong\, F[x]/(x-1) \oplus F[x]/(x+1)\, \cong\, F^2\:$ has nontrivial $(\neq 0,1)$ idempotents, e.g. $\,(0,1),\,$ but $F[x]/(x^2)\:$ does not (as one easily verifies).

Comment: I don't see why $(0,1)$ is idempotent in $F[x]/(x-1) \oplus F[x]/(x+1)$

Comment: @Sergey $(0,1)^2 = (0,1)$ since $(a,b)(a',b') = (aa',bb')$

Comment: thank you. It's my stupid. $(0,1)$ is not trivial.