# What is the meaning that a ring has nontrivial idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

> If $\,{\rm char}(F) \ne 2\ $ then $\,F[x]/(x^2-1)\, \cong\, F[x]/(x-1) \oplus F[x]/(x+1)\, \cong\, F^2$ has nontrivial  idempotents, e.g. $\,(0,1),\,$ but $F[x]/(x^2)$ does not (as one easily verifies).

I do not  understand  the  sentence  that  it  has  nontrivial  idempotents (from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106712/242)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idempotent is an element $r$ such that $r^2=r$ (*idem* is latin for *self*, and *potent* for *power*.  So an idempotent has itself as a power.)

In any ring with unit, the elements $0$ and $1$ are idempotents (just like they are in $\mathbb{Z}$).  So to say a ring has *non-trivial* idempotents is saying that it has idempotents *besides the obvious ones*.

In $R = F[x]/(x^2-1)$, let $y=x+1$ (more precisely, the equivalence class of $x+1$ modulo multiples of $x^2-1$).  Then
$$
    y^2 = (x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 = 2x+2 = 2(x+1) = 2y
$$
This isn't quite an idempotent since we got a multiple of $y$ instead of just $y$.  But remember the assumption that $\operatorname{char} F \neq 2$.  This means we can divide by $2$.

Let $u = \frac{y}{2}$.  Then
$$
    u^2 = \frac{y^2}{4} = \frac{2y}{4} = \frac{y}{2} = u
$$
so $u = \frac{x+1}{2}$ is an idempotent.

As JonathanZ points out in the comments, $\frac{x-1}{-2} = \frac{1-x}{2}$ is another idempotent, for the same reason.

Comment: @ Matthew can  u elaborate   with  counter example,,,as im not  getting

Comment: Note that you can do something similar with $y=x-1$ and come up with a second non-trivial idempotent.

Comment: @JonathanZ thanks; I added that in.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have a ring of the form $R_1\times R_2$ (note that identity here is $(1,1)$), then $e=(1,0)$ and $f = (0,1)$ have the property that $e^2=e$ and $f^2=f$. These elements are called *idempotent*. Note that, in any ring $R$, the elements $0,1\in R$ are idempotent. Those two are called the trivial idempotents. Any other idempotent is called *non-trivial*.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on MatthewL's correct answer:

Let's let $0$ and $1$ denote the additive and multiplicative identities in your field $F$. Then in the *ring* $F \times F$ (which is what they mean by $F^2$) $$(0,0)$$ is the additive identity and $$(1,1)$$ is the multiplicative identity (and both are idempotents). But, as operations in $F\times F$ are component by components it's easy to see that both $$ (1,0) \space \text{and} \space(0,1)$$ are also idempotents, and these are the "non-trivial" idempotents they are referring to.

Notice that we got these non-trivial idempotents using only the very weak assumption that our ring can be written as the cross product of two other rings, so it's a pretty general result.