# Is the ring $\Bbb Z[x] /\langle x^2-1\rangle$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$???

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have the ring $\Bbb Z[x]$. I tried to find that the ring $\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ or not???
I tried to apply the Chinese Remainder theorem. For it I required that ideals $I=\rangle x+1\langle$ and ideal $J$  generated by $x-1$  must be  comaximal.
But unable to get anything.
Please anyone tell is above two rings are isomorphic or not??

Comment: The ring is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. I think you are a bit confused.

Comment: @Bombyxmori  please explain how we show that they are not isomorpic

Comment: At the duplicates, you can see that the idea of using $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)$ are **NOT** comaximal.  Their sum is $(2, x+1)$, which is maximal.

Comment: @Shubhamsingla The duplicates have **multiple** explanations as to why they are not isomorphic. The simplest one IMHO is the one that points out the quotient has two idempotents, but $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ has four idempotents. Are you bothering to read anything here?

Comment: @rschwieb please help how to show that quotient ring has two idopotent elements...

Comment: Ie has only tribal idopotent elements

Comment: @rschwieb please give link of its dublicate answer

Comment: @Shubhamsingla It IS linked.  See the colored box at the top of this post.

Comment: @rschwieb but there is nothing about the co maximal ideal  as you provide Meir I+J= <2,x+1>

Comment: @Shubhamsingla Obviously $x-1$ and $x+1$ are in $(x+1, 2)$, so the sum of their principal ideals is contained in that ideal.   The reverse containment is equally clear.  If you really need another link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251575/29335

Comment: I added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3874356/242) in the linked dupe which makes it much clearer conceptually why no ring factorization exists when comaximality fails.