# Direct product of two rings is never a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, soft-question

I am totally aware of the fact that [If $R$ and $S$ are rings then $R \times S$ is never a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48374/if-r-and-s-are-rings-then-r-times-s-is-never-a-field). I have seen this solution a lot of places. But if I take the multiplication differently, suppose $(r_1,r_2)\in R$ and $(s_1,s_2)\in S$, then I can define the multiplication structure as complex number structure, i.e.,  $(r_1,r_2)\cdot(s_1,s_2)=(r_1s_1-r_2s_2,r_1s_2+r_2s_1)$. I think in this scenario, $R \times S$ produces a field.

If I am wrong, please point out the flaws in my approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the case that $R = S = \mathbb{R}$, this indeed produces a field. However, this is not the _direct product_ of $R, S$ anymore: The direct product is the cartesian product of sets $R \times S$ with the pointwise multiplication specifically, not just any multiplication on the underlying sets.

Comment: @tolUene not only for $\mathbb R$, but we can also do it for any commutative ring with the identity I guess...

Comment: We can't! Take $R = S = \mathbb{Z}$. Try to find an inverse for $(2,1)$. You can't. By the way we get inverses of complex numbers, we know that $(a,b)^{-1} = (da, -db)$ with $d(a^2 + b^2) = 1$, thus we only have inverses when $a^2 + b^2$ is a unit.

Comment: Let $R$ and $S$ rings of square matrices over different fields and of different sizes. How do you define $r_1s_1$?

Comment: The direct product is defined to have *pointwise* product, so if you choose a different product then it is no longer a direct product w.r.t. to that product.

Comment: @tolUene That is really a solution to this post, and should be in the solutions section rather than the comments. Would you consider transferring it?

Comment: @rschwieb Done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be aware that this doesn't define a product at all for $R \neq S$, as in this case, $r_1 s_1$ (etc.) is not defined.

For the case $R = S$, this can indeed form a field; clearly, it works for $R = \mathbb{R}$. However, this is not the *direct product* of $R$ with itself, since this *by definition* (and also necessitated by the universal property of products) carries the pointwise ring structure.

In any case, you do get a ring structure for $R^2$ like this (in fact, this essentially amounts to $R[i]$, for $i^2 + 1 = 0$). From multiplication of complex numbers, we know that $(a, b)^{-1} = (da, -db)$ (if defined) for $d(a^2 + b^2)=1$, thus, $(a,b)$ is a unit in $R^2$ iff. $a^2 + b^2$ is a unit in $R$. For $\mathbb{Z}$, this gives us some easy counterexamples of when this does not form a ring.